# Upgrade from Python 2.7 to 3.7 - Base64 error

Tags: python

I have this line in my code which uses the base64.

```py
output_record = {
            'recordId': record['recordId'],
            'result': 'Ok',
            'data': base64.b64encode((json.dumps((from_dynamodb_to_json(payload["dynamodb"]["NewImage"])), cls=DecimalEncoder) + '\n'))
            }
```

It was running fine with Python 2.7. But after changing the env to 3.7, it's started giving this error.

```py
[ERROR] TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 48, in lambda_handler
    'data': base64.b64encode((json.dumps((from_dynamodb_to_json(payload["dynamodb"]["NewImage"])), cls=DecimalEncoder) + '\n'))
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.7/base64.py", line 58, in b64encode
    encoded = binascii.b2a_base64(s, newline=False)
```

Comment: `.encode('latin-1')` is almost never the right advice, and certainly not here where they are dealing with json

Comment: @TomKarzes nope -- python2 was doing `.encode('US-ASCII')`